# Generate PDF from HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I want to generate PDF from a PHP file that includes HTML controls like textbox, and textarea. I attached CSS in the same. I tried FPDF, DOMPDF and TCPDF, but still I don't get exactly what I want. How do I pass HTML controls with PHP variables and CSS to these libraries?

Comment: I have used `TCPDF` before, but I think [`MPDF`](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) is really great and feature rich and well-documented. I want to give it a try ASAP.

Comment: Off-topic on SO, but on-topic in softwarerecs.SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45903/1834

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) is another option that you could try.

Comment: I also came here looking for a decent solution, mpdf is great and the [manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php) is user friendly

Comment: site down? what happend?

Comment: @themis - what happened is that mpdf migrated to https://github.com/mpdf - these things happen over the years

Comment: I struggled quite a bit with dompdf (mostly because of custom fonts and missing documentation). Then I changed to mpdf and since then my life is much better :)

Answer (score 6):

> **EDIT :**
>   *Found another solution for it, [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is a FLOSS PHP class for generating PDF documents. Looks more dominating library.*

"[PRINCEXML](http://princexml.com/)" is a good library (not completely free now).

Others:

If your meaning is to create a PDF file from [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), pdflib will help you (as some other suggested).

Else, if you want to convert an HTML page in PDF via PHP, you'll find
a little trouble outta here.. For three years I have been trying to do it as best as I
can.

So, the options I know are:

[HTML2PS](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm): same of DOMPDF, but this one convert first in .ps
([Ghostscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript)), then, in whatever format you need (PDF, [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)). For
me it is a little better than dompdf, but I have the same speed problem.. Oh,
it has better compatibility with [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Those two are PHP classes, but if you can install some software on the
server, and access it through passthru() or system(), have a look at
these too:

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/): based on webkit (safari's wrapper), is really fast and
powerful... It seem like it is the best one (atm) for converting HTML pages to PDF on the fly, taking only two seconds for a three pages [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) document
with CSS 2. It is a recent project. Anyway, the [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code) page is often
updated.

[htmldoc](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1): this one is a tank, it really never stops orcrashes... The project
seems to have died in 2007, but anyway if you don't need CSS compatibility
this can be nice for you.

** Thumbs Up For [Strae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80363/strae).

Comment: Another option is [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/php.htm): platform-independent Java library with a PHP wrapper script. Supports HTML/CSS/SVG conversion to PDF, RTF and raster images

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs correctly I don't think any PHP-PDF class would do that.

Mostly you could insert only text and images to a PDF file, so if you would want something that looks like an HTML element you would need to insert it as an image.

Usually just putting HTML doesn't mean all your elements would stay intact in the PDF . (Different world, after all)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.fpdf.org/ is the site having a great HTML-to-PDF class which work well. I am using it, but you have to first study its functionality and then start.