# POST data through javascript through multiple php files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 php files: `request.php`, `action.php`,`mail.php`.

`request.php` generates the page, filling it with different data depending on the `POST` data sent by ajax. It starts as a form, with multiple fields. When you click the `submit` button, ajax sends the form data to `action.php` via `POST`. `action.php` then processes the data, storing it in the database, and generating an html `div` that cleanly lays out the data. `action.php` then uses `html2canvas` and `jsPDF` to to the html `div` into a pdf, which then is passed to `mail.php` via jquery `POST` to be emailed out with `phpmailer`. `action.php` then generates a success message which is sent to `request.php` and displayed.

However, the javascript inside `action.php` that sends the pdf to `mail.php` always fails to run. I've tried a variety of ways to do it, but I can't seem to figure out another way to pass all the data where it is needed, as the data needs to be passed twice: first as an array of raw data, then as a pdf generated by `html2canvas` and `jsPDF`.

If I place a hidden `iframe` of `mail.php` inside `action.php` it will run fine and send the email, but it will be an empty pdf not filled with any of the data from `request.php` (obviously).

I can think of a few potential solutions but I cannot figure out how to implement them:

1) It seems the issue is that javascript doesn't like to run nested, but perhaps there is a way to force the javascript code inside `action.php` to run so that the pdf is generated and sent to `mail.php`.

2) Maybe there is a way to do it all with only one data pass that I am not seeing.

3) Maybe there is a way while inside `action.php` to pass the data array to an `iframe` for `process.php` which would format the html div and generate the pdf and then send it off to `mail.php`,  but I assume even if I could get that done I would run into the same problem of the javascript in `process.php` failing to run and send the pdf to `mail.php`.

Comment: Post your code and we may be able to help.

Comment: You can always use session

Comment: @PhiterFernandes not sure what you mean by use session?

Answer (score 1):

You have a fairly normal (for starting out) misunderstanding of how JavaScript and PHP work together. PHP runs on your server. JavaScript runs on your users' browsers. Based on what you have above, what you are trying to do is:

1. load the initial page via `request.php`
2. process a data request with `action.php` and send a formatted table to the JS
3. have the JS send that table to `mail.php`

What you should be doing instead:

1. load the initial page via `request.php`
2. process a data request with `action.php`

   - have `action.php` call `mail.php`, giving it the table
   - have `action.php` send the table back to the JS
3. have `mail.php` email out the table

You ask why the JavaScript never gets run to send the data to the third script, and that's because you likely never call it. More importantly though, as I show above, you don't need it: just have `action.php` call `mail.php`.

Comment: Added code. I feel like I do have `action.php` call `mail.php`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. Maybe my question will be more clear with example code.

Comment: You are not having `action.php` call `mail.php`. You are having the page rendered by `response.php` (I'm assuming your `index.php` page) send data it is getting from your server (`action.php`) back to your server (`mail.php`). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450696/execute-a-php-script-from-another-php-script) has an excellent answer on how to call PHP scripts from other PHP scripts. Think of it this way: in your current model, I ask for the table, you give it to me, then you ask me to give it back to you so you can email it out. Cut out the middle man.

Comment: I think I am understanding some of what you are saying. But I believe I still need to call JS at some point to generate the pdf. Right now my current model is: Server gives you a form, you fill it out and send it back to the server. Server shows you the results of that form, then the server needs to use JS to essentially take a picture of the form. Then that picture is sent to the server so it can email it out. Even if I have `action.php` call `mail.php`, I still need to run JS at some point before that to generate the PDF so `action.php` has something to pass to `mail.php`

Comment: @tsHunter take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163963/generate-pdf-from-html-php). It (and other questions like it) shows some ways of doing the PFD generation directly in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer I was looking for, but since I knew I didn't want to use php pdf creation as Matthew suggested, this ended up working for me.

Since `request.php` had the javascript that worked with `action.php` anyways, I ended up sending the html table from `action.php` back to `request.php`, and then having `request.php` call `mail.php`.