# Creating a PHP solution for a JavaScript problem in mobile devices

Tags: php, ios, mobile, pdf-generation

I have a PDF form that works on a desktop, but will not work on mobile devices. I tried to write a script to force it to work on iOS and once again, it will work on a desktop, but not mobile devices. Now I need to make this server based and I am out of my league.  What would be the best way to adapt this working code to the web?

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Goalie Performance Survey</title>
    <style>
        .survey-table {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .survey-table th, .survey-table td {
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .survey-table th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.16/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Rate the Goalie Performance (1-4, NR)</h1>
    <form id="surveyForm">
        <table class="survey-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="questions">
                <!-- Questions will be inserted here by the script -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="calculateAndGeneratePDF()">Submit & Print</button>
    </form>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file

```
const goaliePerformanceItems = [
    "Stick Saves", "Glove Saves", "Body Saves", "Blocker Saves",
    "Post Integrations", "Rush Management", "Screens/Traffic",
    "Breakaways", "Puck Tracking", "Patience"
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const questionsTableBody = document.getElementById('questions');
    goaliePerformanceItems.forEach((item, index) => {
        const rowHTML = `
            <tr>
                <td>${item}</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="item${index}" id="item${index}">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="NR">NR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        `;
        questionsTableBody.innerHTML += rowHTML;
    });
});

function calculateAndGeneratePDF() {
    let totalScore = 0;
    let count = 0;
    let itemsAndScores = [];
    goaliePerformanceItems.forEach((item, index) => {
        const answer = document.getElementById(`item${index}`).value;
        if (answer !== "NR") {
            totalScore += parseInt(answer, 10);
            count++;
        }
        itemsAndScores.push({ item: item, score: answer });
    });
    const averageScore = count > 0 ? (totalScore / count).toFixed(2) : "N/A";
    itemsAndScores.push({ item: "Average Score", score: averageScore });
    generatePDF(itemsAndScores);
}

function generatePDF(itemsAndScores) {
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    
    doc.autoTable({
        head: [['Item', 'Rating']],
        body: itemsAndScores.map(is => [is.item, is.score]),
        theme: 'striped',
        startY: 10
    });

    doc.save('goalie-performance-results.pdf');
}
```

This works flawlessly on a Mac or PC desktop/laptop but will not work on an iOS device.  I need an alternate solution.

Thanks for any input you can provide.

Comment: Will not work how specifically? And have you attempted to debug that at all?

Comment: If you want to do this server-side in PHP, you might want to look into something like [mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165218/231316)

Comment: You are using jsPDF 2.4.0. Before abandoning the client-side version completely, maybe try upgrading to the latest version first: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/releases/tag/v2.5.1

Comment: Chris Haas, thank you for that!!!!  I am not an expert coder and don't proclaim to be. I have essentially taught myself what I know.  This solved the problem I was facing and did not have to delve into PHP to solve the problem. Now the question is how to add additional sections and calculate them individually.